# Cannot get value of property based on property name using _.map

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I have an app that uses MongoDB as database and I'm having a hard time pulling property values from array variables. I used a `_.forEach` to check if they have data and it returned positive, however when I tried to get the values based on their property names, I got `undefined`.

Here's my MongoDB model:

```
/* Passport tab schema */
passportInfo: {
    passportDetails: []
},

/* Visa tab schema */
visaInfo: {
    visaDetails: []
},
```

Calling a console.log showed that my `passportInfo` isn't empty:

```
[ { passportExpiry: '2017-03-02T16:00:00.000Z',
    passportNumber: { '0': 'AS1234567' },
    countryOfOrigin: { '0': 'Country Name' } } ]
```

And here's how I tried to pull the values:

```
    _.forEach(results, function (item) {
        console.log(item.passportInfo);

        var temp = _.map(item.passportInfo, "passportExpiry");
        console.log(temp);
```

However after I ran this, `temp` returned `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong?

Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: array does not have any property named "passportInfo"

Comment: Would you mind to create minimal working copy using fiddle/plnkr/jsbin?

Comment: Here's a simple plunker of what I'm trying to do with the same object structure: http://plnkr.co/edit/TYfMhJhnZ0jsdMlDFtke?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of the function `_.map` is waiting for a collection as a first parameter, but in your case the field `passportInfo` is an object. What you need is to pass the `passportDetails` array to `_.map`. Here is a simple way to do that :

```
    _.flatMap(results, function(item){
   return _.map(item.passportInfo.passPortDetails, function(n) {
       return n.passportExpiry;
   });
});
```

[UPDATE] There was a mistake in the previous answer. It is corrected. Since you are using an old version of `lodash`, instead of `flatMap`, use the `flatten` function like this :

```
    _.flatten(results, (item) => {
   return _.map(item.passportInfo.passPortDetails, (n) => {
     return n.passportExpiry;
   });
})
```

Comment: I can't use `_.flatMap` because my lodash version is only 3.10.1. Can I omit that part?

Comment: you can either upgrade your Iodash version or use the flatten function.